On the right path A simple case of if $ab = c,$ then $a \leq \sqrt c$ or $b \leq \sqrt c$
I'm just learning about discrete math and I want to see if I'm on the right path.
So consider if if ab = c, then a ≤ √c or b ≤ √c.
If the statement is true for all real numbers $a$, $b$, and $c$ with $c \geq 0$**

Assume that $ab = c$, but $a > \sqrt{c}$ and $b > \sqrt{c}$.

Since $ab = c$ and $a > \sqrt{c}$, then $a\sqrt{c} > c$.

Since $ab = c$ and $b > \sqrt{c}$, then $b\sqrt{c} > c$.

We get $(a\sqrt{c})(b\sqrt{c}) > c^2$, which simplifies to $ab \cdot
   c > c^2$.

Yet since we said that $ab = c$, we have $c^2 > c^2$, which is a
contradiction.

The statement is true.


If it helps with my analysis, I also wrote the converse and the contrapositive of the statement
Converse: If $a \leq \sqrt{c}$ or $b \leq \sqrt{c}$, then $ab = c$.
Contrapositive: If $a > \sqrt{c}$ or $b > \sqrt{c}$, then $ab \neq c$.

You have made a small mistake in contrapositive form.  There should be word AND instead of OR.

The proof in your bulleted list is correct. It's much wordier than necessary (but that's not a bad thing when you are first learning to write proofs). You could safely and rigorously say

Suppose $ab = c$. If both $a > \sqrt{c}$ and $b > \sqrt{c}$ then
$$ c = ab > (\sqrt{c})^2 = c $$ is a contradiction. So one of $a$ and $b$
must be less than or equal to $\sqrt{c}$.

You could go on to observe that essentially the same argument shows that $a$ and $b$ can't both be less than $\sqrt{c}$. Unless they are  equal one is smaller and the other larger. (It's always a good idea to look at an argument you've written to see if it proves even more than was asked for.)
